# Matching button height inside LinearLayout with Horizontal Orientation

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a tricky situation that I can't seem to wrap my head around. I've got an Android form. I have three elements, a label, a text field (read-only because it's set by a date picker) and a button. Here's what the code looks like:

```
<!-- container: each row in the form stacks vertically -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Here's the date picker element I'm trying to figure out -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:text="@string/set_date_label"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eventDate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:text="@string/set_date_text"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, my form looks mostly correct. But the problem is that the button is vertically taller than the text field, and so it pushes the rows in my form further apart than I'd like. (I can't post a screenshot, because I just joined and don't have enough reputation points. Huh.)

I've been Googling everywhere to try and find a solution, but I just can't seem to figure it out. It's got to be something simple, but I've been banging my head against the desk for a while now :)

Any suggestions? Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you add link with screenshot?

Comment: Good idea. Here: http://imgur.com/jatyKWc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without actually setting the same height for each element, I don't think they will turn out to have exactly the same height.

But one thing you could do is setting the minimum height of the button to zero, which will most likely fix your problem that the button is stretching the whole line.

Do so by using `android:minHeight="0px"` inside the button.

Comment: This did it! I would up-vote you, but I don't have enough reputation. (Again, huh?) Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you! You should be able to accept the answer by clicking onto the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your `TextView`, `EditText` and `Button`'s `layout-height` to `match_parent`.

Comment: This has an effect, but not a good one: http://imgur.com/eQ7Nsz3

The text field ends up being very big, and actually becomes larger than the button.

Comment: @Crankycyclops what effect do you actually want? All in vertical center or all with the same height?

Comment: All with the same height. Florian Schrofner's answer below fixed it for me. Thanks for your help!